# Index based on the value of a converted unix timestamp in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I need to index records based on the value of a UNIX timestamp (seconds since epoch) field, however the index needs to be in the form of `YYYY-MM-dd`. However the value of the timestamp field needs to remain a UNIX timestamp.

So the question is two parts.

1. How can I convert the timestamp file to `YYYY-MM-dd` without destroying the UNIX timestamp?
2. How can I apply the `YYYY-MM-dd` value to the index?

Here is what I have so far.

```
input {
    tcp {
            port => 5000
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
            separator => "  " # <- this white space is actually a tab
            skip_empty_columns => true
            # other fields omitted for brevity
            columns => ["timestamp"]
    }

    #grok {
    #       match => {"indexdate" => "%{NUMBER:timestamp}"}
    #}

    date {
            match => ["timestamp", "YYYY-MM-DD"]
            target => "@timestamp"
    }

    mutate {
            # omitted for brevity
            remove_field => []
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
            hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
            index => "indexname-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
    }
}
```

I have made several different grok attempts but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your `date` filter like this and it should work. The pattern you use in the `date` filter should match the pattern of the field you're parsing, since you have epoch seconds, then the pattern should be `UNIX`:

```
date {
        match => ["timestamp", "UNIX"]
        target => "@timestamp"
}
```

Note that you might need to add a `convert` setting in your `csv` filter to make sure that the `timestamp` field is an integer

```
csv {
   ...
   convert => { "timestamp" => "integer" }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Val, thanks for the answer. I have a followup question if I may? Is there a way to do this that preserves the value of `@timestamp` so that it stays as the current time?

Comment: You can copy `@timestamp` into another field before running the `date` filter. Or you can use another target field in the `date` filter and leave `@timestamp` be. would any of these work?

Comment: So I changed `target => "@timestamp"` to `target => "@mytimestamp"`  and this works perfectly! How does logstach know what field to use when evaluating this line: `index => "indexname-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"`?

Comment: it uses `@timestamp` by default and you cannot change it. however, you can create a new field for that purpose. See this: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-output-index-name-pattern/36428/10?u=val